# python language construct or facility to tag entering and exiting a while loop

Tags: python-3.x

Here's what I want to achieve:

```
while complex_compound_condition_statement:
    foobar() # ... do some stuff
```

I would like the log output of the above to be:

```
<timestamp> INFO: started doing stuff on condition Abc
<timestamp> INFO: condition Abc no longer active
```

To achieve the above using straight control flow, the current code I use does this:

```
while True: # program loop

    if complex_compound_condition_statement:
        log.info(" .... ")
        while complex_compound_condition_statement:
            foobar()
        log.info(" .... ")
```

This has many downsides, in order of severity:

- it is a repetition of code: sometimes the complex condition gets changed in one spot but forgotten in the second spot. This can wreak havoc to operations who get an inconsistent view of log output. Benign but still disruptive is for the logs to keep repeating over and over because the while statement is always false.
- the complex condition *has* to be idempotent: calling it twice in a row cannot have different outcomes
- the complex condition is *code* and has to be executed each time

I've considered weird stuff like putting the log output in a generator that dedups log outputs, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to achieve this in python3.

(for reference, de-duplicating log output process wise doesn't work if anyone else is logging).

Also for reference, this would be the generator method:

```
while True: # program loop
     _log = next(log_output_generator(log))

     while complex_compound_condition_statement:
        _log.send(" .... ")
        foobar()
```

Comment: Have you considered writing a function?

Comment: A with block dealio would do the job wouldn't it?

Comment: @whatsisname you mean between the two whiles? or inside the inner while?

Comment: @JimmyJames a function doesn't work unless I use globals, I have a function of umpteen parameters, or I use a closure. I want to be able to have simple local variables checked against. Think "i > 10 and isinstance(value , dict)"

Answer (score 1):

This should accomplish what you want in a generic manner:

```
def exec_with_log(condition, func, description):
    results = False
    while condition():
        if not results:
            log.info("starting: " + description)
            results = True
        
        func()

    if results:
        log.info("finished: " + description)



while True: # program loop
    def condition():
        return complex_compound_condition_statement

    exec_with_log(condition, foobar, "...")
```

The `condition` local function can reference the variables in the scope of your program loop.  Although, if you don't have that inside a function or other more specific context, everything will be globals anyway.